# Конь: форматирование кода, делая его более красивым

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

```
class Knight:
def __init__(self, row, col, color):
    self.COLOR = color
    if -1 < row < 8 and -1 < col < 8:
        self.row, self.col = row, col
    else:
        print('Находится в неправильном месте')

def can_move(self, r, c):
    if -1 < r < 8 and -1 < c < 8:
        able_to_move = []
        able_to_move.append((self.row - 2, self.col - 1))
        able_to_move.append((self.row - 1, self.col - 2))
        able_to_move.append((self.row + 1, self.col - 2))
        able_to_move.append((self.row + 2, self.col - 1))
        able_to_move.append((self.row + 2, self.col + 1))
        able_to_move.append((self.row + 1, self.col + 2))
        able_to_move.append((self.row - 1, self.col + 2))
        able_to_move.append((self.row - 2, self.col + 1))
        able_to_move = filter(lambda x: -1 < x[0] < 8 and -1 < x[1] < 8, able_to_move)
        return (r, c) in able_to_move
    else:
        return False

def set_position(self, row1, col1):
    if self.can_move(row1, col1):
        self.row = row1
        self.col = col1
```

думаю, полезно будет это не только мне.
как вот эту длинную часть:

```
        able_to_move = []
    able_to_move.append((self.row - 2, self.col - 1))
    able_to_move.append((self.row - 1, self.col - 2))
    able_to_move.append((self.row + 1, self.col - 2))
    able_to_move.append((self.row + 2, self.col - 1))
    able_to_move.append((self.row + 2, self.col + 1))
    able_to_move.append((self.row + 1, self.col + 2))
    able_to_move.append((self.row - 1, self.col + 2))
    able_to_move.append((self.row - 2, self.col + 1))
```

преобразовать в красивый и лаконичный код? Я пытался найти закономерности и даже нашел, но к сожелению, сложить это все в нормальную картину не получилось.
(принципиально новые методы решения, с полным перелопатыванием кода и комментариями, приветствуются)

Answer (score 4):

```py
def can_move(self, r, c):
    return -1 < r < 8 and -1 < c < 8 and abs((self.row - r) * (self.col - c)) == 2
```

#### Upd1:

Произведение целых чисел может дать двойку по модулю только в [восьми](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(x*y)%3D2+integral+solutions) случаях.

Другими словами, если расстояние по вертикали 2, а по горизонтали 1 или наоборот - модуль произведения будет равен двум.

#### Upd2:

```py
def can_move(self, r, c):
    if -1 < r < 8 and -1 < c < 8:
        dx = self.col - c
        dy = self.row - r
        return dx in [-2, 2] and dy in [-1, 1] or dx in [-1, 1] and dy in [-2, 2]
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Можете объяснить как это работает?

Comment: На самом деле, действительно изящное решение. Но нужно быть уверенным, что на вход могут прийти только целые числа. Так как этот код даст ложноположительные срабатывания для, например, хода, при котором смещение фигуры  (0.5, 4)

Comment: @Lisa дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Xander разве что если пользователю доверить вводить координаты вручную, но даже в таком случае это не место для такой проверки, ее нужно сделать выше, общей для всех фигур.

Comment: @extrn, с этим я согласен, в контексте данной задаче вроде бы дробным числам действительно неоткуда взяться. Просто решил нужным отметить, что данный код накладывает несколько большую ответственность на внешний код, чем просто перечисление возможных вариантов :)

Comment: @Xander полностью согласен.

Comment: Так вы можете объяснить как это работает? Какой функцией это все можно было бы все заменить? Я немного путаюсь в такого рода кодах

Comment: @Lisa я уже описал, как это работает, даже не знаю что еще добавить. Что именно вам не понятно? Если что-то конкретное, постараюсь объяснить, если прямо совсем все не понятно, наверное лучше вам просто не пользоваться таким алгоритмом. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Тогда лучше уж буду использовать код снизу, а этот разбуре на досуге что делает да как работает. В любом случае, большое спасибо что отозвались

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import add, sub


def can_move(self, r, c):

    positions = [(f1(self.row, rshift), f2(self.column, cshift))
                 for f1 in (add, sub)
                 for f2 in (add, sub)
                 for (rshift, cshift) in ((1, 2), (2, 1))
                 ]

    able_to_move = [(rn, cn) for (rn, cn) in positions
                    if (0 <= rn <= 7) and (0 <= rn <= 7)
                    ]

    return (r, c) in able_to_move
```